# Reset value of RangePicker Ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using RangePicker from ant design in my app. I'va faced with following issue: when to click on button "reset" I can't clear the value in RangePicker component. Please help me how to do it?  I've tried assign defaultValue but It doesn't work.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the value parameter of RangePicker instead.
Something like this should probably work. Wasnt in a position to make a enviroment and test it but hopefully you get the idea. Ask any questions if theres something that is not clear.

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState('2000-01-01');
const [toDate, setToDate] = useState('2000-01-02');

const onChangeDateRange = (dates, datesString) => {
 setFromDate(datesString[0]);
 setFromDate(datesString[1]);
//More code
}
const onResetClick = () => {
 setFromDate('2000-01-01');
setToDate('2000-01-02');
}

return (
<>
 <RangePicker
      onChange={onChangeDateRange}
      value={[moment(fromDate, dateFormat), moment(toDate, dateFormat)]}
    />
<Button onClick={onResetClick}>Reset</Button
</>
)
}
```

The docs on ant design are very good and at the end you can find all availible parameters a component can have. DatePicker e.g. has a allowClear. https://ant.design/components/date-picker/